# Suppress Script errors in WebBrowser control but still allow popups

Tags: javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am getting vaious script errors when I use a WebBrowser Control to view web pages in my WPF application.  To supress these I used  the 'Silent' method as outlined in this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f686de1-8884-4a8d-8ec5-ae4eff8ce6db/new-wpf-webbrowser-how-do-i-suppress-script-errors?forum=wpf

```
    void wbMain_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSilent(WebBrowser, true);
    }

    public static void SetSilent(WebBrowser browser, bool silent)
    {
        if (browser == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("browser");

        FieldInfo webBrowserInfo = browser.GetType().GetField("_axIWebBrowser2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        object comWebBrowser = null;

        if (webBrowserInfo != null)
            comWebBrowser = webBrowserInfo.GetValue(browser);

        if (comWebBrowser != null)
            comWebBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, comWebBrowser, new object[] { silent });
    }
```

But the problem now is that because the "**Silent**" property has been set none of my web pages right click options work. (There are many right click options on my flash website that pop up various menus).

If I don't use the workaround above then the right click action brings up script error:

"An error has occurred in the script on this page"

How can I get around this?